# How to access array list from another class?

Tags: java, web-services, webserver

We cant access the array list from another class. How can we do that? the program is returning a ServerSOAPFaultException. Client received SOAP Fault from server: Index: 0, Size: 0. The error is returned after running the class that is using the webmethod that is returning the value of the array list.

We created a web service method that returns an integer, the integer is from an array list that came from the web service server. the return value of each webmethod is assigned to a certain variable.

here's our code:

```
int iCounterMinA = iCounterMinSetter();
int iCounterMaxA = iCounterMaxSetter();
int spCounterMinA = spCounterMinSetter();
int spCounterMaxA = spCounterMaxSetter();
int csCounterMinA = csCounterMinSetter();
int csCounterMaxA = csCounterMaxSetter();
int hliCounterMinA = hliCounterMinSetter();
int hliCounterMaxA = hliCounterMaxSetter();
int hlpCounterMinA = hlpCounterMinSetter();
int hlpCounterMaxA = hlpCounterMaxSetter();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to return the whole array list from the webservice. As it is now, it's not possible.